# From the expansion to temperature and recovering equilibrium number densities from the scale factor

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion

For a particle species of mass $m$, when the temperature $T$ of the Universe is $T>m$, the equilibrium number density $n$ falls as $$n\propto T^3\tag{1}$$ and for $T<m$, it falls as $$n\propto  T^{3/2}\exp[{-(m-\mu)/T}].\tag{2}$$ From Boltzmann equation, the equilibrium number density, in absence of any interaction, falls as $$n\propto a^{-3}\tag{3}$$ where $a$ is the scale factor. What is the connection between Eq.(3) on one hand and Eq.(1) and (2) on the other? I have an intuitive feeling that (1) and (2) must be the same as (3) in the because the cooling is caused by expansion so that $a$ and $T$ must be related. In fact, by substituting $a\propto T^{-1}$ in (3) one clearly obtains (1). Is there a similar way to obtain (2) from (3)?

Comment: I am not an expert, but maybe at $T<m$ we cannot say $a \propto T^{-1}$ ? I find a pdf maybe this can help , http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/db275/Cosmology/Chapter3.pdf